# The precise meaning of "legal vortex"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> They were strangers to each other at the time, but nineteen years later,
>   convicted of murder and on the brink of execution, they stood together at the
>   center of a **legal vortex**.
>
> <sub>(Source: the *Introduction* chapter in [*In Search of Sacco and Vanzetti: Double Lives, Troubled Times, and the Massachusetts Murder Case That Shook the World*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Y-KLl13Lq48C&pg=PP11&lpg=PP11&dq=%22They+were+strangers+to+each+other+at+the+time,+but+nineteen+years+later,+convicted+of+murder+and+on+the+brink+of+execution,+they+stood+together+at+the+center+of+a+legal+vortex.%22&source=bl&ots=c-4VjxpUgT&sig=p7wTD-LysXYq-V32h5iK3c3VBig&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22They%20were%20strangers%20to%20each%20other%20at%20the%20time%2C%20but%20nineteen%20years%20later%2C%20convicted%20of%20murder%20and%20on%20the%20brink%20of%20execution%2C%20they%20stood%20together%20at%20the%20center%20of%20a%20legal%20vortex.%22&f=false))</sub>

I am not sure whether "legal vortex" can be understood literally; i.e., they stood together at the center of the precipitous events that were linked to the law. Or does "legal vortex" have some specific meaning?

Comment: The introduction invites the reader to read the rest of the book. You'll find out what it means once you do that. Anyhow, the word obviously cannot be understood literally, and, simplified, it means a complex legal situation with lots of things going on.

Comment: They were at the center of a maelstrom of legal issues. The attributive use of **legal** there doesn't mean that the vortex was legitimate, but that legal issues were involved. That vortex metaphor suggests there was much *controversy*.

Comment: Your understanding is correct, but "precipitous events" is not a *literal* meaning of "vortex".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see why the word *vortex* might be hard for a learner to grasp. I looked at several dictionaries; here are a few definitions I thought might be most helpful:

> **vortex** `literary` (*n.*) a feeling or situation that has so much power or influence over you that you feel you are not in control : *caught up in a swirling vortex of emotions*  ([Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/vortex))
>
> **vortex** `literary` (*n.*) a dangerous or bad situation in which you become more and more involved and from which you cannot escape: *I was sucked into a vortex of despair* ([Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vortex?a=british))
>
> **vortex** (*n.*)  A place or situation regarded as drawing into its center all that surrounds it, and hence being inescapable or destructive: *a vortex of political infighting; a vortex of despair* ([American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=vortex))

I generally see such literary usages worded in the way that the dictionaries have listed, that is:

> *a vortex of* ___________

However, if we tried that with the sentence you've quoted, we'd have to say something like:

> *a vortex of legal troubles*, *a vortex of legal woes*

The author seems to think that two-word phrase *legal vortex* conveys this sentiment rather niftily.

So, the term *legal vortex* simply means a bad and seemingly inescapable problem that is centered on the courts and the legal system.